# MongoDB Query with Java. Count matches in Array

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have data stored in Mongo similar to the following:

```
{
"LIST" : [
    {"NAME" : "a", "VALUE" : "z"},
    {"NAME" : "b", "VALUE" : "y"},
    {"NAME" : "c", "VALUE" : "x"},
    {"NAME" : "d", "VALUE" : "w"},
    {"NAME" : "e", "VALUE" : "v"},
    {"NAME" : "f", "VALUE" : "u"}
    {"NAME" : "f", "VALUE" : "t"}
    {"NAME" : "f", "VALUE" : "s"}
    ]
}
```

I am writing all of this using java.

I receive a list of NAME / VALUE pairs and I must find all records that contain all of these name value pairs. OK, that is easy.

Let A, B, C, D,... represent a single NAME / VALUE pair that I want to find.

Let A represent {"NAME" : "a", "VALUE" : "z"}. Clearly I have a match, that is easy. The actual rule is more like:

Find all documents such that (1) the NAME / VALUE match OR the object does NOT contain an entry for the NAME.

So far, this is pretty easy. I use "$elemMatch" to place the NAME and VALUE to match in the same array element. To check that there does not exist an element with a specific name, I use somethinglike this:

```
new BasicDBObject("LIST", new BasicDBObject("$not", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("NAME", "a"))))
```

I then OR this with the search for a complete match.

Now for the hard part.

I must only return documents that have some minimum number of matches. In my case, I might have 20 NAME / VALUE pairs and I need to match at least 10 of those. Without a similar rule I match every document with zero matched elements.

My best guess is that I need to use some sort of $group
 or aggregation

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using ? and what is the version of the java driver ?

Comment: I am using the latest version of MongoDB. To get the Mongo driver, I added the following to the POM file:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
In other words, I did not explicitly state a version.

Comment: At this point, I would be content to simply say: find me all records that contain 5 of the 10 names, I don't even care if the rest of the query matches, since this would at least provide a lower bound for possible matching and then I can filter the results after wards. Currently, I do manually filter based on the return values.

Comment: In that case I would look at mongodb's aggregation , see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)