# Matching array objects where document has all of any given but not necessarily all given

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "A document",
    "version": "1.0",
    "attributes":
    [
        {
          "name": "a",
          "values": ["1", "2"]
        },
        {
          "name": "b",
          "values": ["3", "4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then for my query, I have been given data that has the same structure as `attributes`. But there might be lots of them, and with all sorts of different names and values. **a** and **b** might be part of it, but there might also be **c** with `["5", "6"]` or **d** with `["1", "3"]`.

What I want is to match all documents where all the attribute objects in the db are matched with any of the given attributes in the query.

So in the database document there might be 2 attributes, and in the query I am giving 6 attributes, and the 2 attributes must find 2 matches among those 6.

Another question I found that I think is asking for the same thing is: [MongoDB Query with Java. Count matches in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151638/mongodb-query-with-java-count-matches-in-array) and I am also leaning towards a similar solution; just filtering on the names in the query and then doing the fine-tuning in code using a stream/pointer to lessen the memory usage.

Comment: could you please provide the expected output for a sample query ?

Comment: @felix, I expect the document as-is. But I want the documents that have all their attributes satisfied by the given attributes. So if document has `{a=1, b=2, c=3}` and I give `{a=1, b=2}` in query, it's not a match. But if I give `{a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4}` it's a match.